# Find the modulus of continuity of $f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, on $I=(0, 1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Find the modulus of continuity of $f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, on $I=(0, 1)$.

The definition of modulus of continuity is $$w(f,r)=\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|:x,y \in I,|x-y|\leq r\}$$
My try:

Let $|x-y|<r$. Let $x=\frac{1}{\pi}$ and $y=\frac{1}{3\pi}$

Then $|f(\frac{1}{\pi})-f(\frac{1}{3\pi})| = |\sin(\pi)-\sin(3\pi)|=|2\cos(2\pi)\sin(-\frac{\pi}{2})|=|-2|=2$

I'm not sure if my method is correct. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Can you write down the definition of modulus of continuity? Your answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Modulus of continuity for function $f$ on interval $(a,b)$ we call function
$$\omega_f(\delta)=\sup |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|,$$
where $x_1,x_2$ are any points from $(a,b)$ with $|x_1-x_2|\leqslant \delta$.

In your case hint can be that function is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ **iif** $\lim\limits_{\delta \to 0+}\omega_f(\delta)=0$.